# parse annotated file

Tags: python, parsing, tags, annotations

I'm trying to parse a file that contains annotation of person names in the form

```
<name> James Gold 

</name> said to meet with <name> Mable Helen  </name> tomorrow night
```

I'm trying to do this with python regex but it isn't working. I'm using

```
annotation = re.findall(' <name>(.*)</name>', lines)
```

I want to recover all entries within the `<name>` tag but these tags could be on different lines. I tried concatenating all lines and removing newline characters but to no avail. any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that it is just an annotated file and not an XML file (use Acorn's solution in that case), you should use some `re` flags to skip the newlines and use the `.` better:

```
>>> src = """<name> James Gold
... </name> said to meet with <name> Mable Helen  </name> tomorrow night"""
>>>
>>> [s.strip() for s in re.findall(r'<name>(.*?)</name>', src, re.DOTALL)]
['James Gold', 'Mable Helen']
```

Then just `strip` the results to get a proper string if it happened to skip a newline. Also, your regex was missing the `?` operator: therefore it was consuming everything up to the last `</name>` tag.

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` is only related to the `^` and `$` special characters and control if these are related only to the whole string or to all of its lines. So it seems not to be needed here...

Answer (score 3):

If the content you are parsing is XML you shouldn't be using regular expressions. Use a parser such as [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml="""
<root>
<name> James Gold

</name> said to meet with <name> Mable Helen </name> tomorrow night
</root>
"""

tree=et.fromstring(xml)

for name in tree.xpath("//name"):
    print name.text.strip()
```

**Result:**

```
James Gold
Mable Helen
```

Comment: From what he posted it doesn't have to be an xml.

Comment: yes, the file is not xml. it's just a series of text with annotation for names in some places. e.g.

<true_name> Kate </true_name> , Power Marketing. Could you please talk to <true_name> Mallory  </true_name> about the counterparty name.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Acorn, you should use an XML parser. If you HAVE to use a regular expression (if it's a school assignment or something) you'll want to use the re.S flag. The . operator by default doesn't match newline characters. re.S will force it to match newline. But then your .* combo is greedy and will match more than you're looking for, so you'll have to tweak your expression.

Comment: it's not a school assignment. it's a project i'm working on. i tried lxml but it threw errors on the file. i'm guessing this is because the file has tags such as <random> that have no closing. i just have to tweak my input a bit then

Comment: If you have control over the file format that would make life a lot easier I'd think. Either way good luck to you!